# How to get rid of passing "username and password" in web service call to Pentaho transformation?

Tags: jetty, pentaho, kettle

I have a requirement where 'XML-response' will be passed in web service call as parameter and it executes a transformation where XML is shredded.

I have designed the transformation in kettle and for accepting web-service request to execute transformation, Carte is up and running on my server.

So, From Server A, client is hitting web-service using URL which is something like below :

```
http://localhost:8081/kettle/executeTrans/?trans=C:\Carte-test\test_2.ktr&response_xml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persons>
    <person>
        <id>1</id>
        <firstname>Samatar</firstname>
    </person>
</persons>
```

On Dev Server B, Carte is up and running and requisite transformation is executed.

But there is a glitch. How to pass "https"(secure connection) rather than "http" in the URL construct i.e. how to make the web service call secure.

My client is obstinate about it.

P.S - We are using "Pentaho 5.4 community edition and hence - no PDI :(" on server B and no Kettle Installation on Server A

Any suggestions!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no notes in documentation how to run Carte most simple way to secure it is to run behind proxy.
Use some Apache, Nging, Caddy configure https protocol and configure proxy to Carte.

As well u can configure basic http authentication on webserver.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that, and it is perfectly well documented on pentaho website. Here you have the instructions to setup a carte server with ssl :

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.0/0L0/0Y0/060/060/010#Configuring_Carte_Servers_for_SSL